# Get all numbers 1-400 randomized in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to get all the numbers between 1-400 listed within a multidimensional array.

I do not want any repeating numbers ( 1 will only be in the array once, as will 18, 100, 385, and so on ) and I do not wish for these numbers to just be completely in order, I want them to be placed in the array at random locations..

*Example (I made this by hand from 1-10):*

```
    var pairs =[
         [3, 9],
         [6, 4],
         [2, 1],
         [5, 8],
         [7, 10],

         //... and up to
         [185, 400]
    ]
```

So, is there any way to make javascript create an array like this automatically, but to much larger numbers?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: what do you mean with "automatically"?, that is really funny for me, you will have to code an algorith for this case, I dont understand what is your expected result, can you please show how example of the result so we can guide you

Comment: If you look at my example array, you will see that the numbers are mixed up from 1-10.  What I'm looking for is a way to make javascript create an array like the example but randomized every time the page is viewed - and the numbers would be from 1-400.  (Sorry, it's hard to put into words..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a standard *Fisher-Yates shuffle* algorithm as follows:

```
function generateRandomPairs(numberOfPairs)
{
  var i, j, numbers, tmp, pairs;

  // fill array
  numbers = [];
  for (i = 0; i < numberOfPairs * 2; i++)
  {
    numbers[i] = i + 1;
  }

  // randomize array really good
  for (i = 0; i < numberOfPairs * 2 - 1; i++)
  {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (numberOfPairs * 2 - i)) + i;
    // swap element i with element j
    tmp = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = numbers[j];
    numbers[j] = tmp;
  }

  // transform linear array to pairs
  pairs = [];
  for (i = 0; i < numberOfPairs * 2; i += 2)
  {
    pairs.push([ numbers[i], numbers[i + 1] ]);
  }

  return pairs;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you!  (I will mark as correct once I can.)

Comment: LOL, no sweat. But I was worried about typos because not running the code always makes you wonder if there's something wrong with it :D

Answer (score 2):

1. fill a one-dimensional array with the numbers from 1 to 400
2. shuffle the array (for instance with a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle))
3. copy the elements of the 1 dimensional array into your multi-dimensional array

Comment: +1 for name of algorithm! Didn't know this was called Fisher-Yates. It 's like something you learn but never know how to call it! Thanks for that insight, I love to have the correct names for things (especially algorithms)!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function range(from, to){
  for(var i=0,n=from,r=[]; n<=to; i++,n++){
    r[i] = n;
  }
  return r;
}
function shuffle(array){
  for(var i=0,l=array.length,n,t,r=[]; i<l; i++){
    n = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1)); t = array[i]; r[i] = array[n]; r[n] = t;
  }
  return r;
}
function randPairsFromRange(rangeArray){
  var l = rangeArray.length;
  if(l % 2 !== 0){
    return false;
  }
  for(var i=0,n=1,s=shuffle(rangeArray),r=[]; i<l; i+=2,n+=2){
    r.push([s[i], s[n]]);
  }
  return r;
}
console.log(randPairsFromRange(range(1,400)));
```